# Reading info files without knowing their path

Tags: commands, ansi-term, term, info

If I'm in a terminal, I can just type `info glibc` and get info about glibc. Since emacs reads info files, it's silly to use `M-x term` to read info files from within emacs. I know you can use `C-u C-h i` followed by the *path* to the info file, but how can I just tell emacs to get info on glibc like I would on the command line?

Answer (score 7):

The info reader in Emacs can be accessed with `C-h i`.  There you can jump directly into the `some-node` node with `g (some-node) RET`.

Alternatively, you can go to the `some-node` node by eval'ing `(info "some-node")`.

Note that the info reader on the terminal picks man pages when info nodes cannot be found.  There is no "glibc" info node, but just a man page.  To read man pages within Emacs just use `woman`, e.g. `woman RET glibc RET`.

The info node for the GNU C library is called "libc", so you should run `(info "libc")` instead.

Eshell has a function `eshell/info` with the following documentation:

```
Run the info command in-frame with the same behavior as command-line
`info', ie:
  'info'           => goes to top info window
  'info arg1'      => IF arg1 is a file, then visits arg1
  'info arg1'      => OTHERWISE goes to top info window and then menu item arg1
  'info arg1 arg2' => does action for arg1 (either visit-file or menu-item) and then menu item arg2
  etc.
```

For example, to access the Emacs info documentation in an Eshell session you can just type `info Emacs`.  For the libc documentation run `info libc` in an Eshell session.

Comment: So I need parentheses around glibc?

Comment: I updated the answer.  There is no "glibc" info node, just a "libc" info node.  What you see on the terminal is the "glibc" man page.  To read man pages use `woman`.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... indeed `C-u C-h i` doesn't seem to let you do that.
OTOH, you can do

```
C-h i g (glibc) RET
```

Comment: You can try that, it doesn't work

Comment: That only searches nodes within the emacs info tree, not the general info tree

Comment: Emacs uses the general info tree (potentially complemented with Emacs's own info tree).  The `info` command also supplements the general info tree with its own tricks (mostly looking up manpages), so maybe that's what you're seeing.  `M-x man RET glibc RET` should give you something similar, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ivy-mode` on from the package [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper),
after pressing <kbd>g</kbd> you get this:
[image]

In this case, the input is `li`. But with no input, it gives me a list
of 137 files that I have in alphabetical order.